# Cordova index.html from Express+Handlebars layout.hbs?

Tags: cordova, express, handlebars.js, templating

Utilizing Handlebars with Express to inject `.hbs` files from `/views` into the layout.hbs `{{{body}}}` tag,
how can this structure be converted for utilization with Cordova, which is based on index.html?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not that familiar with express, but the templating aspect should be fairly straightforward with Cordova and Handlebars. Christophe Coenraets has a tutorial on Cordova basics that also covers using Handlebars that can be found here: https://ccoenraets.github.io/cordova-tutorial/handlebars-templates.html

In particular, the call:

```
var homeTpl = Handlebars.compile($("#home-tpl").html());
```

compiles the template, and the call:

```
$('body').html(homeTpl());
```

sets the body element's html to the compiled template code.

I've got a similar setup with my app using [MarionetteJS](http://marionettejs.com) for the MVC classes. It's a little more complicated, but at the basic level it's just compiling the handlebars template using `handlebars.compile()`, and then setting the html for the `<body>` element on the index.html page whenever the user navigates around the app.